# Cross-browser way to implement default string description of object

Tags: javascript

When you create a class, and then instantiate it, and then request its string description, you get a result in the format `[object {type}]`. Here's an example:

```
function TestClass(){}
var instance_obj = new TestClass();
Object.prototype.toString.call(instance_obj);

// Output: [object Object]
```

Is there are cross-browser way to implement a custom description such that when I run the above code, I get the following?

```
[object TestClass]
```

So far, I've done this:

```
// Option 1
function TestClass(){}
var instance_obj = new TestClass();
instance_obj[Symbol.toStringTag] = 'TestClass';
Object.prototype.toString.call(instance_obj);

// Output: [object TestClass]
```

...and also this:

```
// Option 2
function TestClass(){}
var instance_obj = new TestClass();
Object.defineProperty(TestClass.prototype, Symbol.toStringTag, {
    value: "TestClass"
});
Object.prototype.toString.call(instance_obj);

// Output: [object TestClass]
```

`Option 2` appears the best option given that it does not expose a writable `Symbol.toStringTag` directly on the instance.

However, according to the docs for [Symbol.toStringTag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol/toStringTag#:%7E:text=The%20Symbol.,accessed%20internally%20by%20the%20Object.), it appears to be a modern feature that won't work on most browsers.

Is there a cross-browser [`>=IE9`] way to implement this?

Comment: "*[When you] request its string description, you get a result in the format `[object {type}]`.*" - no, you get that only when you call `Object.prototype.toString`. If you simply overwrite the `toString` method of your class, you can get anything you want.

Comment: What is your actual goal here? What problem are you trying to solve? In outdated browser that don't support `Symbol.toStringTag`, you can still overwrite `Object.prototype.toString` itself if you cared.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks for the suggestion for overwriting `Object.prototype.toString`; it didn't occur to me initially. However, I'm having some implementation issues with regard to doing that. I posted another [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65076114/range-error-when-overriding-object-prototype-method-with-function-constructor) and would appreciate if you could chime in.

Answer (score 0):

Pursuant to @Bergi's suggestion to overwrite `Object.prototype.toString`, the following works to specification:

```
(function(toString){
    Object.prototype.toString = function(){
        if(this instanceof TestClass)
        {
            return '[object TestClass]';
        }
        return toString.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})(Object.prototype.toString);

function TestClass(){}
var instance_obj = new TestClass();
if(window.Symbol)
{
    Object.defineProperty(TestClass.prototype, Symbol.toStringTag, {
        value: "TestClass"
    });
}
Object.prototype.toString.call(instance_obj);
```

Tested on IE9 and IE11.

You may also find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65076114/range-error-when-overriding-object-prototype-method-with-function-constructor/65076621#65076621) useful.