# Range error when overriding Object.prototype method with Function constructor

Tags: javascript, recursion, function-constructor

I'm trying to override `Object.prototype.toString` in a bid to add functionality for additional class descriptions.

Here's the initial code:

```
(function(toString){
    Object.prototype.toString = function(){
        if(this instanceof TestClass)
        {
            return '[object TestClass]';
        }
        return toString.apply(this, arguments);
    }
})(Object.prototype.toString);

function TestClass(){}
var instance_obj = new TestClass();
Object.prototype.toString.call(instance_obj);
```

When I run this in the console, I get the following output:

```
[object TestClass]
```

The good thing is that it doesn't drastically modify the way `Object.prototype.toString` works, so with another type [i.e. not TestClass], things work just as expected e.g. `Object.prototype.toString.call(12)` will output `[object Number]`.

This implementation works with no issues so far. However, I have another implementation with the following code:

```
(function(toString){
    var fn_code_str = `return function(){
        if(this instanceof TestClass)
        {
            return '[object TestClass]';
        }
            
        return toString.apply(this, arguments);
    }`;
    var pre_fn = new Function(fn_code_str);
    Object.prototype.toString = pre_fn();
})(Object.prototype.toString);

function TestClass(){}
var instance_obj = new TestClass();
Object.prototype.toString.call(instance_obj);
```

With this, I get the proper output for TestClass, but when I use something else, like `12`, I get a RangeError:

```
VM527:5 Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at Function.[Symbol.hasInstance] (<anonymous>)
    at Number.eval (eval at <anonymous> (getElements.html:19), <anonymous>:5:21)
    at Number.eval (eval at <anonymous> (getElements.html:19), <anonymous>:10:29)
    at Number.eval (eval at <anonymous> (getElements.html:19), <anonymous>:10:29)
    at Number.eval (eval at <anonymous> (getElements.html:19), <anonymous>:10:29)
    at Number.eval (eval at <anonymous> (getElements.html:19), <anonymous>:10:29)
    at Number.eval (eval at <anonymous> (getElements.html:19), <anonymous>:10:29)
    at Number.eval (eval at <anonymous> (getElements.html:19), <anonymous>:10:29)
    at Number.eval (eval at <anonymous> (getElements.html:19), <anonymous>:10:29)
    at Number.eval (eval at <anonymous> (getElements.html:19), <anonymous>:10:29)
```

This appears to be an issue with recursion of `toString.apply`. However, I can't figure out why this second implementation is recursing, if the first one does not?

**Note**: The reason for this second implementation is to add the type-checking code [i.e. `if(this instanceof MyClassType){return '[object MyClassType]'}`] for different classes dynamically from a list of class names in an array. In other words, rather than modifying code for each new Class I come up with, I append the class name to the array instead, and the conditional statement is generated automatically.

Comment: Why would you use the `Function` constructor?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `toString` parameter of your IIFE is not in scope in your `new Function` code. Instead, it uses the global `toString` = `window.toString` = `Object.prototype.toString`.

To fix this, you need to declare the `toString` variable inside the `new Function`'s code to make the returned closure work. Either as a simple constant:

```
(function() {
    var pre_fn = new Function(`
    const toString = Object.prototype.toString;
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return function(){
        if(this instanceof TestClass) {
            return '[object TestClass]';
        }
            
        return toString.apply(this, arguments);
    }`);
    Object.prototype.toString = pre_fn();
})();
```

or as a parameter:

```
(function() {
    var pre_fn = new Function('toString', `
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^^
    return function(){
        if(this instanceof TestClass) {
            return '[object TestClass]';
        }
            
        return toString.apply(this, arguments);
    }`);
    Object.prototype.toString = pre_fn(Object.prototype.toString);
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
})();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. 'Used the second option.